# how to define a signal and catch it in the linux kernel code

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, signals

Well, I want to modify the kernel, define a SIGNAL (let's say #define SIGHELLO 33) and catch it (let's say printk "lalalalala"). I know where to define, but failed to catch it. (The program outputs unknown signal and terminates) I am not sure where to inject. Hope someone knows.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confused by the purpose and handling of signals. With two special exceptions (SIGKILL and SIGSTOP/SIGTSTP), signals do not receive special handling in the kernel. (They can be caught in userspace using `signal()` *etc*.)

That being said, signal handling is in `kernel/signal.c`. I don't believe that the behavior in this file can be modified by kernel modules.

Comment: What I am trying to do is a little different. I want to send a signal from one process to another in the kernel. And once the other process receive the signal, it will do something. I guess SIGUNUSED could be a help.

Comment: If it's going to be both generated and handled in the kernel, why does a signal need to be involved? Is there some reason you can't just perform the signal's action directly?

Comment: I want to track down a process's process space information and cpu state when the scheduler switches to that process. This means whenever I want to track that, I run a syscall in another process, and DO SOMETHING TO REMIND that TARGET PROCESS to do that ITSELF. That's why SIGNAL is involved here.

Comment: The linux kernel itself doesn't support sth like ReadProcessInformation (process1, address1) something like that.

Comment: I'm not sure what ReadProcessInformation() is supposed to be, but it sounds like a description of `ptrace()`. Signals are not a reasonable way to implement this -- it'd make much more sense to implement within the existing framework of `ptrace()` or the `perf` profiling system.

Comment: ReadProcessInformation (not sure about its exact name) is a windows system call. It takes in a virtual address of a process, length and the process id and returns the exact content. This includes getting page table, mapping virtual address to physical address and getting the content. Anyway, I think ptrace() is just another way of hacking. Have any idea how to do ReadProcessInformation with ptrace()?

Comment: `ptrace()` with `PTRACE_PEEKUSER` will let you read memory contents of a process you're tracing. You can also use `/proc/<pid>/mem`.

Comment: Thx a lot for your help! For /proc/<pid>/mem, it cannot be accessed directly?

Comment: You have to be ptracing a process before you can access its memory.

Comment: But it requires that the ptraced process is the child process of the ptracing process?